# How to log workflow foundation activities

Tags: logging, workflow-foundation

I have a task to add logging functionality to the existing workflow based solution. There is a layered architecture : BusinessLayer->AgentLayer->StoreLayer. At the business layer there is a xaml activity which consists from a one or more agent activities. Agent activity consists from one or more store activities. Agent and Store activities are inherited from CodeActivity.

Activities are executed by

```
WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(activity);
```

My task is to log the execution of each activity. The log output. should be e.g.

```
BusinessActivity1 has been started at 11:00 8.2.2012
AgentActivity1 has been started at 11:01 8.2.2012
StoreActivity1 has been started at 11:02 8.2.2012
StoreActivity1 has been ended at 11:03 8.2.2012
AgentActivity1 has been ended at 11:04 8.2.2012
BusinessActivity1 has been ended at 11:05 8.2.2012
```

So my question is what is the best practise to log something like this. I don't want to write the LogMessage to the each activity. I prefer the unified solution. Is there exists any clever solutions?

thanks

Comment: Just an idea: you could create a custom activity that wraps all other activites in a workflow. This custom activity could perform log actions every time an activity inside it is executed.I've seen that schema working before (I don't have any code, sorry), and with it a system was able to track execution of workflow services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WF already supports a logging structure which it calls [WF Tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee513992.aspx). You would be wise to just follow the existing infrastructure so you don't incur any unnecessary performance overhead.

You need to look at how to incorporate [`TrackingParticipants`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.tracking.trackingparticipant.aspx). You will need to replace the [`WorkflowInvoker.Invoke()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.workflowinvoker.invoke.aspx) with [`WorkflowApplication`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.workflowapplication.aspx) (*or create an instance of `WorflowInvoker`*) so that you can add your custom `TrackingParticipant` via [WF Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517415.aspx). By defining a [`TrackingProfile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.tracking.trackingprofile.aspx) you can restrict the tracking messages to only those which you are interested by trace level, event type, and tracking record.

If you wish to log your own custom [`TrackingRecords`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.tracking.trackingrecord.aspx), you can derive from the base `TrackingRecord`.

Alternatively - you could build a wrapping custom activity as suggested by @Gabocat, but this will incur additional performance overhead that WF Tracking would not.

Comment: Thanks guys for inspiration. I will use Tracking functionality.

Comment: +1 Good one. Forgot about tracking, and the scenario I mentioned was used on early version of WF.